# SharePoint window is minimized on opening

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

i face the following problem, when opening a delegate window, for example to upload a document to a document library i get the following screen size:

http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/1079/errorky.png  (Cannot post image under 10 rp)

Ofcourse this is not desired, my question is what settings i have to adjust to get a normal dialog box.

Any questions or comments about my question are appreciated.

Comment: This is not normal. Try adjusting the size manually using and then try reloading this window and see if the size stays.

Comment: Does this behavior continue when you change the Document/Browser Mode from IE 7/8/9?

Comment: I know there is probably something wrong in my code but i don't know what, i tried to adjust manually but don't know which css class to adjust

Comment: @UrbanDude Wauw! when i put it in ie modes 7 8 and 9 it works fine, but when i put it in compatibilitymode ie9( standard) it shows this behavior, what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this many times in my SharePoint site.

We had problems with others browser, we had to explaint our customer, "since it's a Microsoft tool, you'll have to use IE"

Bu that was just part of the problem, seems to be a CSS problem, you'll have to do a script to make the users to use IE 8.

I'm sorry, i know this doesn't help too much, but we have like a year working with SharePoint, and seems a too expensive tool for all the problems it cause, because we also had to deal with the sinchronization of profiles, but that's another story that cost around a month and a lot of money on consulters).

Comment: So you mean i will force their browser to run in IE8 mode?

Comment: @nldev Probably will be the best solution, it really hard to try to make a SharePoint site in other browser than IE

Comment: yes i understand, well since i use no specific ie9 tools i will try forcing it, thanks for the help!